# Multiselect rows in JSF table

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf

Required to sort a datatable in jsf (not using rich,prime faces) and the table should have multi-select option to select particular rows. So that the selected rows can be deleted.
using delete button in the form.

Could anyone kindly provide some idea how to do this using ajax or normal jsf stuff?
am using JSF 1.2 version.

I have done google search, yet I couldnot able to see any examples.

Any Help is appreciated

Comment: I faced this requirement some weeks ago. Do you have an specific doubt or are you asking for the whole solution?

Comment: If you have solution for it. It would be great help for  me if u share your suggestions or solution.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 different questions. For sorting you can simply use "tomahawk" library's "Datatable" tag which contains attribute named "sortable". you just have to set it "true" and it will solve your problem.

put this entry in your page

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" prefix="t"%>
```

To delete the multiple selected row bind your datatable with htmlDataTable and take a boolean value in your bean.like this...

```
       <t:dataTable binding="#{bean.htmlDataTable}" 
        sortable="true">
```

column of the datatable

```
          <t:selectBooleanCheckbox id="select1" value="#{item.editable} valueChangeListener="#{bean.yourMethod}" onclick="submit()">
```

here editable is boolean value in your bean.

To delete the row

```
   for(int i=0; i<yourList.size(); i++)
    {
      YourBean obj=(yourBean)htmlDataTable.getRowData();
      if(obj.isEditable())
      yourList.remove(i);

     }
```

Comment: Yhank you rishi. I know it can be done easily using a4j or faces 2, but if anyone knows any good way to achieve this in jsf 1.2, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Binding with htmlDatatable is not a feature of JSF 2. I had this requirement some time ago and i have implemented it in same way in jsf 1.2. By a4j you can just use "a4j:commandButton" to prevent your page from refreshing. Logic will be same as I explained.

Answer (score 0):

Use [h:dataTable](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_dataTable.html) to display your rows from an ArrayList of POJO.This POJO should have a boolean value to denote its selection.(The ArrayList of POJO must be in your Managed Bean.)
Then map that boolean variable to a h:selectBooleanCheckBox in a column and render.

Example of how to use the h:selectBooleanCheckBox

For deleting the selected Check Box,write a method in your Managed Bean for accessing the selected values from the data table and remove it from the ArrayList and render the page.

For sorting ,follow a similar approach of writing a method in your ManageBean that will perform sorting on the arrayList when a commandLink/commandButton button for sorting/deleting is clicked.
Note : I am not much aware of using Ajax with Faces 1.2,so my approach would be like wrapping the data table with a h:form and submitting this form to access the methods for sorting,deleting.